# How to create a Java object in C++ using JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, sip

I want to initialize a SIP connection using native Android API and Qt Android Extras (JNI) and Qt. If I was programming in Java, I will create a SipProfile object to start a connection but in JNI (As I know) I just can execute methods in classes.

**Can I create an object of type of a Java class?** Am I have to do this?

**Does QAndroidJniObject does this for me?**

This class reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.html

Sample code:

```
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
...

SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
mSipProfile = builder.build();
```

Sample reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Update:
**I'm not using JNI itself. I'm using "Qt Android Extras".**

Comment: do you want to create SipProfile.Builder object using JNI?

Comment: In fact, I want to stablish a SIP connection. Then I need to create objects :-)

Answer (score -1):

I used to know how to do this.  Please forgive me if the answer is incorrect.  I hope this gets you started.

You get a jni handle for the constructor you want to run.  Then allocate/create a jobject and run the constructor on it.